# Der, das oder die "Einzelne"

Tags: article

In [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Einzelne.html), it shows that the single form of "Einzelne" is a `NOUN`, which can be `der`, `das` or `die`.

However, in other places (e.g. [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/Einzelne.html), or Google translate), it is `der`.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which one is correct?

dict.cc is correct. *"Einzelne"* can be used for all genders in german, hence with all articles *der*, *die* und *das*.

> - Der Einzelne <sup>(Mann)</sup> ist da machtlos.
> - Die Einzelne <sup>(Frau)</sup> kann viel für die Gemeinschaft tun.
> - Das Einzelne <sup>(Ding)</sup> ist nicht viel wert.

Comment: Your examples use it as adjective not a noun, also they should be lower case then

Comment: @AhmedAshour No it's not adjective. Note that I've put _Mann_, _Frau_ and _Ding_ in parenthesis there. If _"Einzelne"_ is used as a noun, its mostly in reference to another sentence, but it can stand alone. Also if used as adjective the word wouldn't be capitalized.

Comment: Nouns made from adjectives are capitalized as all other nouns are. Unlike other nouns, they always come in all three genders. *Der/die/das Nächste, bitte.*

Comment: @Janka What is the correct term for these? _Adjective noun_ is a different thing as I've researched.

Comment: In English, this is called *nominalized adjective*, e.g. *the rich*. In German, *nominalisiertes Adjektiv* is at least understood.

Comment: `Mann`, `Frau` und `Ding` legen den falschen Kurzschluß nahe, dass es eine sprachliche Identität von grammatischem Geschlecht und biologischem gäbe.

Comment: Es war schlicht das Einfachste für das Beispiel, und ist sowieso nur eine sekundäre Annotation.